# How to solve gradle:2.2.0 can't build success with DefaultManifestParser

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0

Recently I updated android studio to 2.2 and updated gradle to gradle:2.2.0. However, com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser cannot be resolve after the update. if I use gradle:2.1.3 , it is working. How to solve gradle:2.2.0 can't build success .Thanks

```
String getVersionName(manifestFile) {
    def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser()
    return manifestParser.getVersionName(manifestFile)
}

int getVersionCode(manifestFile) {
    def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser()
    return manifestParser.getVersionCode(manifestFile)
}
```

> Error:A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> Error:(16, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Answer (score 1):

Default manifest file now has only one constructor, which has parameter. So calling constructor with no parameters produces this weird error. Also methods now don't have a parameter.
Change your code to:

```
String getVersionName(manifestFile) {
    def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(manifestFile)
    return manifestParser.getVersionName()
}

int getVersionCode(manifestFile) {
    def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(manifestFile)
    return manifestParser.getVersionCode()
}
```

Comment: Also add import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser in the beginning of your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `YOUR PROJECT -> gradle -> wrapper -> gradle-wrapper.properties`
2. Open it with notepad
3. Replace `gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` in this line `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip` with your gradle. In this case `gradle-2.2.0`

Hope it helps